# Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /path/to/file on line 2

Tags: php, sqlite, centos

I am trying to use sqlite3 with php on CentOS. I have followed the following steps to install sqlite3.

```
$ sudo yum install php5-cli php5-dev make
$ sudo yum install libsqlite3-0 libsqlite3-dev
$ sudo yum install php5-sqlite3
$ sudo yum remove php5-sqlite3
$ cd ~
$ wget http://pecl.php.net/get/sqlite3-0.6.tgz
$ tar -zxf sqlite3-0.6.tgz
$ cd sqlite3-0.6/
$ sudo phpize
$ sudo ./configure
$ sudo make
$ sudo make install
$ sudo apache2ctl restart
```

However, the last step, that is to restart apache I have not executed as I have no httpd installed on my system(and I don't want to).

Since sqlite is serverless, is it really necessary to have apache installed? Although I am not sure if not restarting apache is causing the error, but almost every help link I found related to this issue it is mentioned we need to restart.

My sqlite3.ini file has the extension enabled.

```
extension=sqlite3.so
```

I have also tried

`sudo yum install php5-sqlite3 
 sudo yum install php5-sqlite`

Please provide suggestions how to use sqlite3 programmatically.

My PHP code:

```
<?php
   class MyDB extends SQLite3
   {
      function __construct()
      {
         $this->open('testdb.db');
      }
   }

?>
```

ERROR:

```
Fatal error: Class 'SQLite3' not found in /path/to/file on line 2
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: may be wrong namespace? 
try: class MyDB extends \SQLite3

Comment: @mochalygin still getting the same error. But what do you mean by wrong namespace?

Comment: check `php -m` from terminal as you say your sqlite3.ini contains `extension=sqlite3.so` but usually it resides in php.ini

Comment: @MASIDDIQUI with php -m i see that there is SQLite and not SQLite3, so I tried 'MyDB extends SQLite', but getting the same error of 'class not found'.

Comment: try putting `extension=sqlite3.so` php.ini and restarting  apache it should run .. I just tested it works perfectly

Comment: I have two php.ini files in different locations: '/usr/lib/php.ini' and
'/etc/php.ini' . I added 'extension=sqlite3.so' in /etc/php.ini but still getting the same error. Also I am using php for scripting and have no need for apache, so I don't have it installed on my system. @MASIDDIQUI

Comment: `/etc/php/(cli/apache2)/php.ini` the part in bracket are two different folders to be modified separately for running cli and apache

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141345/discussion-between-anusha-and-m-a-siddiqui).